# Changing ringer mode not working at first time in android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, telephonymanager, android-broadcastreceiver

Below is my callreceiver brodcastreceiver which will call when any phone call will come. problem is i am changing ringer mode to silent when any phone call comes. but its not working at first time. and then working fine after that.
i tried many times but still not working for first time when call. help me to figure out this issue.

**CallReceiver.java**

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String TAG = "CallReceiver";

    AudioManager audioManager;
    TelephonyManager telephony;
    ComponentName receiver;
    PackageManager pm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onReceive ");
        receiver = new ComponentName(context, RingerModeStateChangeReceiver.class);
        pm = context.getPackageManager();

        audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String Number) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, Number);
                Log.e(TAG, "Number: " + Number);

                if (state == 2) {
                    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

                } else {
                    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                }


            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: that is only an asumption, but I guess it is not possible to change (or device dependant). I guess the ring comes as first in your device some ms before the receiver reveives the intent.

Comment: In the TelephonyManager API, there are three states EXTRA_STATE_RINGING, EXTRA_STATE_IDLE and EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK. So EXTRA_STATE_RINGING seems to be fired only if it´s ringing, which makes it impossible to get before...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  Then why its working after that every time..??

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Look, I guess (and really guess, I don´t know), ***AS FIRST***, the ringtone comes in and ***THEN*** the broadcast is received. So you can only change the loudness after the first ring.

Comment: I wonder why it works at all, because if `state==2` means `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`. So from your code, it shouldn´t work even after the first ring...

Comment: What if you try to get the number as first directly, ***outside*** the listener at the beginn of the receiver. If you get a number, there must be a call, then set the mode to silent. It´s just an idea, I would test it without the `PhoneStateListener` ..... `intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)`

Comment: Or, if this does not work, check the intent with : `Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");`